# How to Set Venue for Event using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I create events, I've tried adding venue details similar to what it looks like below, but the venue information seems to be ignored. (I'm posting it to /me/events)

The event otherwise gets created successfully. How can I set the venue during the creation process? Do I need to create it afterwards instead? Thanks

```
{
  "owner": {
  "name": "David R",
  "id": "234234"
},
"name": "sdf",
"description": "tes",
"start_time": "2011-09-11T00:00:00",
"end_time": "2011-09-11T03:00:00",
"location": "sadf",
"venue": {
"street": "weber",
"city": "Waterloo",
"state": "Ontario",
"country": "Canada"
},
"privacy": "SECRET",
"updated_time": "2011-09-10T23:22:23+0000",
"type": "event"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

get rid of '"venue"{}' and just use city state country etc..

```
{'name':"neverland",
'city':"los angeles",
'description':"ontherparty",
'location':"sames",
'start_time': "9-12-2011 12:45"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it, it worked without a problem.

Comment: the facebook documentation still tells you otherwise. facebook is soo damn ignorant. thanks for the hint!